# Binded scope not change correctly

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive composite of input and select tags all source code available in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/80xUu27i6i6nd96q6maz?p=preview)

I am newbie in angularJS and this is my first directive after read some tutorials.
when i change select options Binded scope item1 not change correctly!!!!
I expect item1 must updated with selected item in selectedchanged function

Thanks to any help or improve

codecombo directive template :

```
<span>
    <input ng-model="code" ng-change="codechanged()">
    <select ng-model="selecteditem" ng-change="selectchanged()" ng-options="item as item[propertytitle] for item in list" class="codecombo-select"></select>
</span>
```

codecombo script :

```
   app.directive('codecombo', function($compile) {
  return {
 restrict:'A',
            scope:{
                propertyid:'@',
                propertycode:'@',
                propertytitle:'@',
                list:'=' ,
                selecteditem:'=',
                selectedchanged:'&'
            },
            templateUrl:'template.html',
            link:
            {
                 pre: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                     /*make some property optional*/
                     if(!attrs.propertytitle) attrs.propertytitle="title";
                     if(!attrs.propertyid) attrs.propertyid="id";
                     if(!attrs.propertycode) attrs.propertycode="code";
                 },
                 post: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                    var select=element.find('select');
                    var input=element.find('input');


                    /*some code delete for save space ...*/

                    scope.code;

                     /*select option changed*/
                    scope.selectchanged=function(){
                        console.log('select-changed');
                        console.log(scope.selecteditem);
                        if(scope.selecteditem!==null){
                            fillSelectedProperties(scope.selecteditem);
                        }
                        else
                            emptySelectedProperties();

                        scope.selectedchanged();
                    }

                     /*input text changed*/
                    scope.codechanged=function(){
                        console.log('code-changed');
                        scope.selecteditem=findByCode(scope.list,scope.code);
                        console.log(scope.selecteditem);
                        scope.selectchanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

});
```

codecombo usage in index.html :

```
<div codecombo list="testlist" selecteditem="item1" selectedchanged="selectedchanged()"></div>
```

This is controller :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.testlist=[
    {id:1,code:100,title:'Item no.100'},
    {id:2,code:200,title:'Item no.200'},
    {id:3,code:300,title:'Item no.300'},
    {id:4,code:400,title:'Item no.400'}
  ];

  $scope.selectedchanged=function(){
    /*
    i want do some staff with item1 here and expect to be updated for each selectedchanged
    but seem it has previous value 
    */

    console.log($scope.item1);
    $scope.title=$scope.item1.title;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the change listener (`ng-change`) fires before the update of the field of the external scope. The scope synchronization is implemented with a `$watch` of the variable in the internal scope that updates the variable in the external.

Having said that, I would propose removing the `selectedchanged` attribute and implementing it as a watch in the parent controller. I think it achieves the same result, with slightly less code:

```
$scope.$watch("item1", function(newval) {
    console.log($scope.item1);
    $scope.title = $scope.item1 != null ? $scope.item1.title : "-";
});
```

(By the way do note the `null`/`undefined` check.)

Forked plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/3Ur9N9fEduXQU2xehFC8?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the answer, is " the change listener (ng-change) fires before the update of the field of the external scope" normal behavior of angular or some thing wrong on my impelementation of directive?i wish to vote up this answer, but this is my first question and apparently i need 15 reputation to vote up.

Comment: You have nothing intrinsically wrong in your code, so I guess it is normal behaviour. Btw, you can flag this answer as correct (this can change if a better answer appears), regardless of your reputation.